# JQuery Ajax call to be triggered onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to JavaScript, Jquery and Ajax. This is what I am trying to do:

I have a button in my HTML code, and I want to trigger an AJAX call which will make a GET request to a web server running on my local machine.

This is what I have so far:

JS code:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$('call').click(function() {
    alert("hiii");

  $.ajax({
    'url' : 'localhost:8080/blah/blah/blah',
    'type' : 'GET',
    beforeSend: function() {
                alert(1);
            },
    error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            },
    'success' : function(data) {
      if (data == "success") {
        alert('request sent!');
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

HTML code:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <div class = "buttons">
          <input type="submit" id="call" value="call">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's going wrong? The URL looks suspect -- might want to put an `http://` or `https://` on it.

Comment: Ok, correct me if I am wrong, I should at least see the alert('hiii'); when I click the button, right? I am not even getting to that step.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few issues with your code. For one, your selector is not pointing at any class or ID. You need to use `.call` or `#call` for a class or ID respectively. Second, your script has no `document.ready` function. Check out the code below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // document.ready function
    $(function() {
        // selector has to be . for a class name and # for an ID
        $('.call').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from reloading page
            alert("hiii");

            $.ajax({
                'url' : 'localhost:8080/blah/blah/blah',
                'type' : 'GET',
                beforeSend: function() {
                   alert(1);
                },
                error: function() {
                   alert('Error');
                },
                'success' : function(data) {
                   if (data == "success") {
                        alert('request sent!');
                   }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @NightOwlPrgmr mentioned your selector is erroneous. To correct this you have to use the `#call` and not `.call` as this is an id and not a class attribute. Also the `Document.ready` function will ensure your code runs after all the html elements have been loaded. This will mitigate the risk of trying to use an element that has not been created yet. A sample code similar to the one above is:-

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <div class = "buttons">
              <input type="submit" id="call" value="call">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // document.ready function
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // selector has to be . for a class name and # for an ID
            $('#call').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from reloading page
                alert("hiii");

                $.ajax({
                    'url' : 'localhost:[port_number_web_server]/blah/blah/blah',
                    'type' : 'GET',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                       alert(1);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                       alert('Error');
                    },
                    'success' : function(data) {
                       if (data == "success") {
                            alert('request sent!');
                       }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```